# What preposition I should use here: "a job at/in/on/another Junior-engineer position"?

Tags: prepositions, in-on-at

Speaking about a job.

> I've found a job at/in/on/another Junior-engineer position.

What preposition would be appropriate here?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is pretty awkward (at least to my American ears).  I think it needs to be reworded. There are a few options.  The most natural would be:

- I've found a job as a junior engineer.

Another option which more closely follows your original might be:

- I've found a job in a Junior engineer position.

But that sounds overly formal to me.